# Problems to sets the fragment from a FragmentScenario to be used from DataBindingIdlingResource

Tags: android, testing, data-binding, android-espresso, google-codelab

I'm following [this Google Codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/advanced-android-kotlin-training-testing-survey#0) and at the **page 8** (Task: End-to-End Testing with Data Binding), at **step 8** (Write DataBindingIdlingResource) you have to create a file called `DataBindingIdlingResource.kt`.

```kotlin
class DataBindingIdlingResource : IdlingResource {
    [...]
}

private fun View.getBinding(): ViewDataBinding? = DataBindingUtil.getBinding(this)

/**
 * Sets the activity from an [ActivityScenario] to be used from [DataBindingIdlingResource].
 */
fun DataBindingIdlingResource.monitorActivity(
    activityScenario: ActivityScenario<out FragmentActivity>
) {
    activityScenario.onActivity {
        this.activity = it
    }
}

/**
 * Sets the fragment from a [FragmentScenario] to be used from [DataBindingIdlingResource].
 */
fun DataBindingIdlingResource.monitorFragment(fragmentScenario: FragmentScenario<out Fragment>) {
    fragmentScenario.onFragment {
        this.activity = it.requireActivity()
    }
}
```

**The problem:**
is the last function `fun DataBindingIdlingResource.monitorFragment` because `fragmentScenario.onFragment` provides only `onFragment(action: Nothing)` and not `onFragment {}`.

How Can I solve this issue?
Thanks.

Comment: I am having the same issue and confused why the type is marked as Nothing - did you figure it out?

Comment: The definition does not show a type of `Nothing` https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/testing/FragmentScenario#onfragment

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155557836

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fun DataBindingIdlingResource.monitorFragment(fragmentScenario: FragmentScenario<Fragment>) {
  fragmentScenario.onFragment { fragment ->
      this.activity = fragment.requireActivity()
  }
}
```

This is working for me.

Answer (score 7):

I've solved it by changing the definition to

```
fun <T : Fragment> DataBindingIdlingResource.monitorFragment(fragmentScenario: FragmentScenario<T>) {
```